# creating a list view that displays by time range - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list-form

I have created a list of employees that are on call for certain portions of the day.  For example:
Employee A is on call 2019/04/11 0000-1500 hrs 
Employee B is on call 2019/04/11 1500-2359 hrs

I want the view to only show the person who is on call 'in the moment'.  Using the [Today] function shows both employees regardless of what time someone is viewing the list - I would like just the employee that is 'currently on call' according to what the current time is to be displayed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the volatile [Now] function, unfortunately - without editing the CAML code for the view.  And [Today] only returns a date, without time.  Therefore you will probably need to use Client Side Rendering and the JSLink property of list view web parts (to attach the JavaScript CSR to your list view web parts)

CSR is not documented very well, but some very helpful code samples reside [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). There is also a Chrome Plug-In that makes CSR development much easier [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en).